# Mapping two values, suggestion for better formula

Tags: arithmetic

Given values for `original` from 0 to 100, I need to calculate `result`
where:

`original` = 0 corresponds to `result` = 2000

and

`original` = 200 corresponds to `result` = 200

Currently I am using this formula:

```
result = maxValue - (original * coefficient)
```

A simple example:

---

```
original    result    coefficient    maxValue
0           2000      18             2000
1           1982
2           1964      
3           1946      
4           1928
5           1910
6           1892
7           1874
8           1856
9           1838
10          1820
20          1640
80          560
90          380
91          362
92          344
93          326
94          308
95          290
96          272
97          254
98          236
99          218
100         200
```

---

I would like to know:

- a) If you could suggest me a different formula, please write an example and a brief simple term explanation.
- b) Which formula to use to find out `original` if I know only `result` (reverse), example for `result` = 1820, `original` should be 10 and so on.

Comment: Please feel free to suggest a better title and tag if you think it is appropriate, as I am new user of this community :) thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "clever" ? What is there to be improved ?

Comment: That seems to be $\;f(x):=2,000-18x\;,\;\;x\in\{0,1,2,3,...,100\}\;$

Comment: $$y=ax+b\to x=(y-b)/a$$

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have edited my question. Could you please add a simple explanation (like step by steps) as I am not really familiar with the sign in your formula, thanks.

Comment: If you also use my named variables in the answer I would appreciate it